# IIS cannot connect to machine

Tags: iis-7, assemblies

I use a Windows Server 2008 R2. When I try to open the IIS Manager, I get the following error:

[image]

It says that the file containing the connections and settings is corrupted and it restores the original one.

When I try to connect to the website, I get this:

[image]

It says that there was an error when tried to connect and if I like to enter my authorization data again. Also, it cannot load the System.Web file or one of its dependencies.

I reinstalled IIS and checked if the GAC contains the mentioned assembly. It is there and when I tried to remove it, it said programs needed it so cannot remove. 
I copied the *applicationHost* config file from *history* to system32\inetsrv\config but it still shows the errors.

What could cause this and what else should I do to repair IIS?

Comment: maybe an error translation would help, it looks like something is misconfigured with the IIS Application Pools. Is it in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Yes, it is. I try to find a translation